# Appear extra worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I had face some problem regarding excel vba about while i entering this function to generate the new worksheet and named it. But it generate extra new worksheets. Below is the coding.

```
Function add_sheet_by_branch(ByVal branch As String) As String


    For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
        If LCase(Sheets(rep).name) = LCase(branch) Then
            MsgBox (branch & " " & "already exists!")
        Else
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.name).name = branch
    Sheets.Delete
    add_sheet_by_branch = name
End Function
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: How many worksheets do you want to generate? 1?

Comment: more than 10++ worksheets

Comment: Your code is having a logical error. You are looping through each sheet and if the name of that sheet is not equal to `branch`, you create a new worksheet

Comment: @sam092: I am sorry, just noticed your comment.

Comment: @sam092: Would you like to post an answer? I will delete mine.

Comment: @SiddharthRout How gentleman of you :) Nope it's okay. You don't have to delete yours. I'm not posting an answer ;)

Comment: @sam092, thanks you all precious comment and correction on my code. I will try it later on. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thanks you all precious comment and correction on my code. I will try it later on. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

You are creating a sheet every time the sheet name doesn't match.

```
Function add_sheet_by_branch(ByVal branch As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(branch)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add _
        after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = branch
        add_sheet_by_branch = Name
    Else
        MsgBox (branch & " " & "already exists!")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Rout, after I had implement your corrected code, it runs well. But just some simple confusing in my brain. Why the message box is continue popping out instead of pop out one time? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using that function as a userdefined function? i.e in an excel cell?

Comment: If yes, then change the line `MsgBox (branch & " " & "already exists!")` to `add_sheet_by_branch = branch & " " & "already exists!"`

Comment: because i pass to this function from previous function. Don't know why it will happen to it. :(

Comment: So is your problem sorted?